# Vue.js 2: How to bind to a component method?

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJS (v2) component with a private array of objects `this.private.messagesReceived` which I want displayed in a textarea. The array should be converted to a string by a method/function and Vue is blocking all my attempts to bind. Every attempt results in my serialization function (converting the array to a string) only being called once and never again when the data changes.

I feel there must be a way to do this without `Vue.set()` or some forceUpdate shenanigans.

https://jsfiddle.net/hdme34ca/

#### Attempt 1: Computed Methods

Here we have the problem that Vue only calls my computed method `messagesReceived1` once and never again.

```js
<script>
{
  computed: {
    messagesReceived1() {
      console.log("This is called once and never again even when new messages arrive");
      return this.private.messagesReceived.join("\n");
    },
  ...
  methods: {
    addMessage(m) {
      console.log("This is called multiple times, adding messages successfully");
      this.private.messagesReceived.push(m);
    }
  }
<script>
<template>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40" v-model="messagesReceived1"></textarea>
</template
```

#### Attempt 2: Binding Methods

Here Vue decides it doesn't like moustaches inside a textarea `{{ messagesReceived2() }}` and balks. It also doesn't allow `messagesReceived2()` or `messagesReceived2` in `v-model`.

```
<script>
{
  methods: {
    messagesReceived2() {
      return this.private.messagesReceived.join("\n");
    },
    addMessage(m) {
      console.log("This is called multiple times, adding messages successfully");
      this.private.messagesReceived.push(m);
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40">{{ messagesReceived2() }}</textarea><!--Nope-->
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40" v-model="messagesReceived2()"></textarea><!--Nope-->
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40" v-model="messagesReceived2"></textarea><!--Nope-->
</template
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a data variable and set its value in the function. Then bind variable with textarea, not directly with the function.

Comment: Yes, but I was really wanting to understand why the computed and method bindings do not work.